# Passenger stand alone uses wrong ruby version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, passenger

Hello im using rails 4 with rvm - ruby verison 2.0.
But when i try to start passenger (stand alone) im getting syntax-errors.

It tells me:

```
Ruby interpreter command
/usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

How can i change it to the rvm 2.0 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem:  passenger standalone uses nginx, and after upgrading my app to use ruby 2.1.1 (specified in the .ruby-version), I saw similar errors.

On my production server, I know where the nginx configuration lives, so I could fix the path to the ruby interpreter.

However on the standalone setup I couldn't find it in less a minute, so I did a `gem uninstall passenger` followed by `gem install passenger` to have it recompile nginx.

Now it works, at least until the next ruby interpreter bump.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ruby first:

```
rvm use ruby
```

it might display additional instructions - make sure to read them

Comment: Still the same issue, I reinstalled passenger. ruby -v returns: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]

Comment: you need to refine your question then, include more details about what configurations do you use and where do you get the error